# How to draw and save rectangles into a rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, html5-canvas

I am trying to build an application that allows the user to set pre-defined regions over a map background. Rather than specifying X,Y coordinates I want them to be able to draw the regions on top of the map and then hit save. I then want to record those shapes to the database so I can present them again later on.

I have been looking at tutorials such as this one:

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-resize-and-invert-images/

How would I go about starting to create this kind of functionality? Where should I look? I understand it is a large question and perhaps a little too broad but a list of options to consider would be an amazing answer.

If anyone has any tips on where I can get started it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

That's a job for javascript. Ruby and HTML cannot do this alone. Basically in your javascript code you will have to listen for some events that trigger your save action(the user resizes the image or drags it away), then collect the data that you want to save(image position & size I guess) and then send this to the backend via an AJAX request. Then you can store it in the db.

Comment: Awesome thanks. I've been hacking on this all afternoon. I can get the html5 canvas to pass back values to the JS. Can you recommend what I should be googling for to learn about ajax requests and saving the data to a rails app from them? Thanks!

Comment: Sure, jQuery has an AJAX API. No problem there. I'm pretty sure Prototype has something like that too, but jQuery is kind of becoming a standard in my eyes http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/